# Powershell Popup Message with timer

Tags: powershell, timer, popupwindow

Hello my programming gods...

I'm trying to create a popup message with timer with powershell to include with SCCM scripts. This popup will be called if a program needing update is detected.

What I want is something like this that I found on the net:
[image]

Basically:

1- I want to be able to put a banner in the popup window.

2- The name of the program to be updated

3- Show a timer

4- When the timer is expired or the next button is pressed, the script would continue and installed the update.

I began thinkering with this tutorial: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/building-a-countdown-timer-with-powershell/

So far the timer works but everything is pretty barebone. Am I on the right track? How would you go about it? Also, the popup window don't go to the foreground... Dunno what Im doing wrong.

I am not a programmer and I'm trying to do this as a favor for someone. I just don't really know how I should go about it. Maybe powershell is not the good tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a tool such as below:

- https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/
- https://github.com/PSAppDeployToolkit/PSAppDeployToolkit/releases

PS-App-Deployment Toolkit provides a set of functions to perform common application deployment tasks etc.

I use this myself for handy deployments to users within my workplace through SCCM.

See the above links for instructions and detail.